# How to discount delivery charge from grand total in magento 2 using coupon code?

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento , developing a website where no shipping avail.but delivery charges available for every order.

Here i am using coupon code , but coupon only avail to base total not grand total(inclusive delivery charge). How to achieve this function . (Magento 2)

For now i used,grand total as sub total

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cartObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    //$subTotal = $cartObj->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); //Current Cart Subtotal
    ***$subTotal*** = $cartObj->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //Cart Grand total
```

Still it's not working good

Thanks,

Comment: Please post the relevant code for what you have tried.

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: I am using coupon code , but it minus only base total , not grand total ... so delivery charge remains same